# Set and modify model value depending on other model value

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, hash

I have this model:

```
class GiftCard extends Model

{
    use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'number',
    'hashed_number',
    'security_code'
];

protected function securityCode(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn(string $value) => Crypt::decrypt($value),
        set: fn(string $value) => Crypt::encrypt($value),
    )->shouldCache();
}

protected function number(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn(string $value) => Crypt::decrypt($value),
        set: fn(string $value) =>  Crypt::encrypt($value)
    )->shouldCache();
}

protected function hashedNumber(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        set: fn(string $value) => hash('sha3-512' , $value) . Config::get("app.card_pepper"),
    )->shouldCache();
}

}
```

The model in the DB

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('gift_cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('number');
        $table->text('hashed_number');
        $table->text('security_code');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

What I'm trying to do is automatically use the `number` to fill the field `hashed_number` because it depends on it and I don't want to give it as parameter. Is there a way to do it with mutators and remove `hashed_number` so the model looks like:

class GiftCard extends Model

```
{
    use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'number',
    'security_code'
];
.....
```

Comment: You can access any value of a Model in an Attribute, i.e. `protected function example(): Attribute { return Attribute::make(get: fn() => $this->number); }`. Calling `$giftCard->example` would return the value from `Crypt::decrypt($value);`

Comment: And, FYI, Laravel can do automatic encryption via the `Model::$casts` property. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#encrypted-casting

Comment: @miken32 that's a good idea thanks

Comment: @TimLewis I was trying to do it so I have not to handle the attribute each time

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way to do it:

```
class GiftCard extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'number',
    'security_code'
];

protected function number(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn(string $value) => Crypt::decrypt($value),
        set: fn(string $value) => [
            'number' => Crypt::encrypt($value),
            'hashed_number' => hash('sha3-512' , $value) . Config::get("app.card_pepper")
        ],
    )->shouldCache();
}
}

protected function securityCode(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn(string $value) => Crypt::decrypt($value),
        set: fn(string $value) => Crypt::encrypt($value),
    )->shouldCache();
}
```

In the set function return multiple attributes, the model in table:

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('gift_cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('number');
        $table->text('hashed_number');
        $table->text('security_code');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```